# DataSet event raising too much times

Tags: c#, events, dataset

I have DataSet with Change/Remove events:

```
adapterNB = new DocumentProductsNBAdapter();
adapterNB.Connection = conn;
adapterNB.ClearBeforeFill = true;
adapterNB.Adapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = true;
adapterNB.Adapter.AcceptChangesDuringFill = true;

adapterNB.Fill(ds.DocumentProductsNB, documentID);
productsDG.DataContext = null;
productsDG.DataContext = ds.DocumentProductsNB.DefaultView;
productsDG.ItemsSource = ds.DocumentProductsNB.DefaultView; 
if (!firstTime)
{
   ds.DocumentProductsNB.DocumentProductsNBRowChanged +=
      new WarehousesDataSet.DocumentProductsNBRowChangeEventHandler(updateNB);
   ds.DocumentProductsNB.DocumentProductsNBRowDeleted +=
      new WarehousesDataSet.DocumentProductsNBRowChangeEventHandler(updateNB); 
   firstTime = true;
}
```

bool `firstTime` is set to false at the begining (when entering to window).

Problem is that, when I put breakpoint in event:

```
void updateNB(object sender, WarehousesDataSet.DocumentProductsNBRowChangeEvent e)
{
   //(....) breakpoint here
}
```

Event raises exactly `2 x GridView.Items.Count` times. So for 10 products in grid, event raises 20 times. Does anyone know why? Im sure about that I dont have any other += event for "ds".

Thanks!

I've put that lines in updateNB event:

```
 Console.WriteLine("Products count: " + productsDG.Items.Count + ", Action: " + e.Action + ", how many times I was here (i with i++ parameter): " + iI);
                iI++;
```

Result:

> (...)
>
> Products count: 35, Action: Add, how many times I was here (i with i++
>   parameter): 68
>
> Products count: 35, Action: Commit, how many times I was here (i with
>   i++ parameter): 69

Comment: normally, you only subscribe the event the first time (your code does the opposite); is there any chance this is just a bool reversal gone sour?

Comment: @MarcGravell, although the user is using his `firstTime` property back to front, I don't believe that *that* is causing his problem.

Comment: If you comment out your `DocumentProductsNBRowDeleted` handler assignment, does the handler just get hit `GridView.Items.Count` times?

Comment: Actually in updateNB event i have if(e.Action == DataRowAction.Change) and DataRowAction.Delete, it does actually nothing (because action is Add/Commit for example), but it's strange that event fires so many times

Comment: After I comment out event for RowDeleted, it doesnt really go to updateNB (nothing strange), but at this momment I got 31 products in grid, and after I've added one more, in e.Action i have: e.Action 
Add
e.Action 
Commit
e.Action 
Add
e.Action 
Commit from immediate window - that repeats 64 times(32x2 as add/commit)